# How to prevent bootstrap from removing my styles?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple div for which I load html content with jquery method load().  This content uses bootstrap tab panes. In it's simple form it is something like that:

```
<div id="div-loaded">   -- the content of this div was loaded
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane active">
        <table class="table-mytableclass">  --- this class gets overwritten by it self
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    ... some table content
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <div>
    ... other tabs
```

The problem is that the correct style class is applied for only for a fraction of a second and then it is changed back to bootstrap defaults. If I  (in FF) select context menu option reload CSS, there is again this fraction od a second and then my style get changed to bootstrap default. Why does this happen? How can one prevent this? How does one change a look of content?
And a side question? In tab in my listing above, this is copied form an example found on net, is it mandatoray to have a  tag inside

item?

Additional info:
- cannot reproduce in jfiddle.
- if i force inline style it works. As if class is somehow "removed".

Comment: Can you set up a demo that reproduces the issue?

Comment: when you link in your css files, does bootstrap come before your styles or vise versa? The order matters in priority of the styles.

Comment: I agree with @JosephDailey. Sounds like the stylesheets are being called in the wrong order.

Comment: My styles are last. But i tried to make them ver specific: ie table.table-maytableclass {...} and so on. It is a funny efect, just a short blip of correct look and then the default little fonts. Working on jfiddle example of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your bootstrap styles are taking priority over your styles.

The order goes, I believe:

1. inline styles: `style="key:value;"`
2. !important modified: `key:value!important;`
3. by selector specification: `#id is more specific than .class`
4. Order of reference: `the latest style takes priority`

So in your case I, without seeing the HTML, believe you have placed the bootstrap link after your own styles link.

Comment: No. My link is last. Could it be that the load() method does not put together a correct document?